# How can I detect the component change when using Angular component router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Right now I'm using ui-router to handle the authorization:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {}
```

But how can I use ngComponentRouter to make this work since Angular1.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new router you have **[Component Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.github.io/router/lifecycle)**:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['user', '$http', MyController]);

function MyController(user, $http) {
  this.user = user;
  this.$http = $http;
}

// Before switching to a new component, this hook runs for 
// each active component in the app. If any of them 
// return false, a rejected promise, or a promise that resolves to false,
// the navigation is cancelled.

MyController.prototype.canActivate = function() {
  return this.user.isAdmin;
};

//This hook fires just before the nagivation finishes.

MyController.prototype.activate = function() {
  return this.bigFiles = this.$http.downloadBigFiles();
};
```

Comment: How can I redirect the user to the '/login' page when he hasn't loginned yet?

Comment: With the canActivate hook

Comment: But how? there is no '$componentChangeStart' like $stateChangeStart event to listen

Comment: You have the canActivate hook, before you will move to this component angular will trigger this function. It's the same as stateChangeStart.